# Maximum indices in D3DFMT_INDEX16 index buffer

Tags: 3d, gpu, direct3d

I'm doing work on older GPUS which only support 16bit indexes for `DrawIndexedPrimitive` calls (and I assume the same for OpenGL as a hardware limitation).

While I understand this means obviously all indices have to be under 0xffff and therefore at most 65k *vertices*, I can't find a good answer to what limit this means for the maximum number of polys you can draw at once. Does it mean the index buffer is also limited to 65k elements - about 22k triangles - or could you send 100k triangles at once if you wanted to, from your 65k indices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of the indices you happen to use in a draw call is not related to the size of the index.

Comment: Thanks. I always figured there was also a limit on how _many_ indices but I guess either not, or it's unrelated.